# Being 'transfered' to another company, how to explain in CV

Tags: job-change

I work as a developer in Company A, which provides its services to another Client Company.

Client Company is very close(has good relationship) to Company A and also another one - Company B, while both Company A and Company B are close to each other.

I was asked by my Company A, if it is okay to trade me away to Company B because of some internal communications between A and B, I agreed as there will be no change in my workflow, everything will be same as before, just the company tag above my head will be different. Plus Company B will increase salary by some amount as compensation of some kind.

**The problem:** I am with Company A for about 5 month, and after transfer is occured, it will look like I resigned from Company A and started working with Company B, I am afraid it can be interpreted as job hopping.

**The question**: How can I clarify this situation to future employers?

Comment: This is incredibly commonplace in software.  (Particularly with anything related to the government food trough.)  it's so totally common it's a non-issue, everyone will know what happened.  Contract, then permanent.

Comment: @Fattie Agreed. It is very common for contractors get "traded" between companies. I don't think it would create a problem unless you don't write it down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You describe the change as having minimal impact on your work, save that you have a different 'tag above your head' and that the salary is better. If you're worried about it being misinterpreted, it may be worthwhile treating them as one job on the CV, with you merely being transferred rather than appearing to be fired and hired (references from HR in both companies will surely back this up too).

If for example in your CV, you bullet-point your roles and responsibilities within Company A, you could always write it as:

> ***Company A / Company B - DateFrom to DateTo:***
>
> - *Attached to long-term project X in client company 'Company B'.*
> - *Permanent transfer arranged to Company B (effective from DateHere).*

I did this once before on my CV when the company I worked for was bought over and largely re-purposed. Employers will know this sort of thing happens and likely not get suspicious. Again, your references will back this up. It will likely still come up in the interview, especially if Company B is your most recent employer; it'll be up to you to explain the transition process and put their minds at ease.

Comment: I really like that approach putting both Companies as a workplace, thanks

Comment: It´s also not so uncommon nowadays as a lot of businesses are organized into different legal entities. Happened to me for the third time now, to my wife two times throughout her career.

Comment: This is also how I handle it. There is an important distinction to make between a "company" in the legal/name sense, versus a "company" in the sense of "a group of people who get a thing done." You had a change in the first, which likely doesn't mean as much to an employer as a change in the second.

Comment: You can even name it by contract, instead of companies. Like "Stack Exchange Contract - From A, to B" then list the two companies. That way it's understood as the same contract.

Answer (score 1):

I've had happen (twice!) at previous employers.

I list on my resume as:

- Company A.  Sept 1994 - Oct 2007
- Company B acquired company A in Oct 2007.
- Company C acquired company B in Jan 2009.

No need to over think this.

Comment: In my case company B didn't acquire Company A, they just came to some agreement about our team. Our workplace remain the same, working on the same project

Comment: I was in the same cube for 21 years with the three companies.

Comment: The way I listed the companies is by keeping the contract name at the top, then in each "company" I write the to/from dates and my responsibilities. That way it's listed as "one" job that's owned by multiple companies.